# How can I format the output of this JSON in CakePHP?

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I am using CakePHP to send JSONS to my Android Application. I currently have this function in my model which gets me the nearest locations within a certain radius of a certain place:

```
public function getNearest($lat = 54.980503, $lng = -1.614349, $radius = 25, $max = 30)
{
    $query = "SELECT *, 
             ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('$lat') ) * cos(radians(`lat`)) 
             * cos(radians(`long`) - radians('$lng') ) 
             + sin( radians('$lat') ) * sin( radians(`lat`) ) ) ) 
             AS distance FROM locations HAVING distance < '$radius' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , {$max}";
    return $this->query($query);        
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
class LocationsController extends AppController
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');
    public $viewClass = 'Json'; 
    function index()
    {
        $locations = $this->Location->getNearest(); 
        $this->set(compact('locations'));
        $this->set('_serialize', array('locations'));
    }
}
```

This is the output it gives me in normal array format:

```
array(2) 
{ 
    [0]=> array(2) 
    { 
        ["locations"]=> array(9) 
        { 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["name"]=> string(20) "Newcastle University" 
            ["terrain"]=> string(1) "5" 
            ["difficulty"]=> string(1) "2"
            ["ratings"]=> string(1) "4" 
            ["uid"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["long"]=> string(8) "-1.61624" 
            ["comid"]=> NULL 
            ["lat"]=> string(7) "54.9787" 
        } 
    [0]=> array(1) 
    { 
        ["distance"]=> string(19) "0.14548355269404845" 
    } 
 } 
 [1]=> array(2) 
 { 
    ["locations"]=> array(9) 
    {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["name"]=> string(10) "Vale House" 
        ["terrain"]=> string(1) "4" 
        ["difficulty"]=> string(1) "3" 
        ["ratings"]=> string(1) "4"
        ["uid"]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["long"]=> string(8) "-1.58939" 
        ["comid"]=> NULL 
        ["lat"]=> string(7) "54.9849" 
    } 
    [0]=> array(1) 
    { 
        ["distance"]=> string(18) "1.0352356381517442" } 
    }
}
```

If I turn on the JSONView class in CakePHP, I get this:

```
{
   "locations":[
      {
         "locations":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Newcastle University",
            "terrain":"5",
            "difficulty":"2",
            "ratings":"4",
            "uid":"2",
            "long":"-1.61624",
            "comid":null,
            "lat":"54.9787"
         },
         "0":{
            "distance":"0.14548355269404845"
         }
      },
      {
         "locations":{
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Vale House",
            "terrain":"4",
            "difficulty":"3",
            "ratings":"4",
            "uid":"2",
            "long":"-1.58939",
            "comid":null,
            "lat":"54.9849"
         },
         "0":{
            "distance":"1.0352356381517442"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, there's a lot of unnecessary strings in there, for example, why are there 3 locations? Why is distance separate?

It would be great if the output could be along the lines of:

```
{
    "locations":
    [{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Newcastle University",
            "terrain":"5",
            "difficulty":"2",
            "ratings":"4",
            "uid":"2",
            "long":"-1.61624",
            "comid":null,   
            "lat":"54.9787"
            "distance":"0.14548355269404845"
    },
    {
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Vale House",
            "terrain":"4",
            "difficulty":"3",
            "ratings":"4",
            "uid":"2",
            "long":"-1.58939",
            "comid":null,
            "lat":"54.9849"
            "distance":"1.0352356381517442"
    }

   ]
}
```

Comment: I think this is the default behavior since you define a custom column aside the *, Cake populate the entry `locations` with all columns, then, put the custom field inside a separate entry. Can't you change the hydration? Otherwise you'll have to do this on your own.

Comment: What do you mean by hydration?

Comment: I don't really know Cake, but the ORM should handle different hydrate method. Hydration is when ORM take result from database and transform them into *what you want*. Could be: object, array without keys, etc ..

Comment: also: use virtual fields here - this way distance would be in the right array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @j0k mentions, using `*` in a SQL statements is 'select all columns from the database table'. Because 'distance' is a calculated field it is *not* 'part' of a specific table and therefore not prefixed with 'locations'. CakePHP will include those fields in a separate 'key' in the result set. However, it shouldn't be hard to rewrite the structure of that result array.

**why are there 3 locations ?**
Because you're asking the database to return *'up to 30 locations within a 25 radius'** with your query (although I see only *two* in you example)

**note**
You're using custom queries but do not escape/sanitize your values. When using custom queries, CakePHP will not do that for you, allowing SQL injection. Please handle with care! Note that CakePHP *does* support prepared statements (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements)

The best option is to rewrite your query to a standard CakePHP `find()`. You'll probably need to create some virtualFields for this to work; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

I'm not at my computer at the moment, but if you need additional examples, I may be able to write something up